# Solving $\mathbf{Bx}=\mathbf{z}$ with $\mathbf{B^T B} = \mathbf{A^T A} + \lambda \mathbf{I}$ for large matrix $\mathbf{A}$

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I come across a problem to computationally solve $\mathbf{x}$ from $\mathbf{Bx}=\mathbf{z}$ with $\mathbf{B^T B} = \mathbf{A^T A} + \lambda \mathbf{I}$ for large matrix $\mathbf{A}$. The variable $\mathbf{z}$ is a known $n \times 1$ vector, $\mathbf{A}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $\lambda$ is a real number. The problem is that the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is very large so it is almost impossible to save every elements of $\mathbf{A}$, but we can compute $\mathbf{Ax}$ and $\mathbf{A^T x}$ for every $n\times 1$ vector of $\mathbf{x}$.

If $\lambda = 0$ (such that $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{A}$), I can solve it by minimizing $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}) =  \frac{1}{2} \| \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{Ax} \|^2$  using the family of gradient descent algorithms, with gradient $\nabla_{\mathbf{X}} \mathcal{L} = -\mathbf{A^T} (\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{Ax})$. I tried applying the same method with $\lambda \neq 0$, and obtain the gradient, $\nabla_{\mathbf{X}} \mathcal{L} = -\mathbf{B^T} \mathbf{z} + \mathbf{B^T Bx}$. I can calculate the second term on the right hand side of the equation, but I got stuck on calculating the $\mathbf{B^T} \mathbf{z}$ term. Any ideas on solving this problem?

Comment: What do you mean, you "got stuck"? Did the code run forever? Also: Which variables are given? Are A, B, z and $\lambda$ already known?

Comment: "got stuck" means I don't know how to calculate the term because the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are very large (e.g. $10^6 \times 10^6$). $\mathbf{z}$ and $\lambda$ are known. The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is known indirectly (i.e. I can compute $\mathbf{Ax}$ and $\mathbf{A^T x}$, but no way to save every elements of the matrix).

Comment: Ok, so B is not known, not even indirectly. Is it feasible to compute $B^T$ indirectly? You could interpred the matrix as a $n$ vectors that are computed from $A$ and $\lambda$ and apply this vector to $z_i$.

Comment: That's the problem (i.e. computing $\mathbf{B^T}$ indirectly). Interpret the matrix as $n$ vectors is also not straightforward to solve the implicit expression for $\mathbf{B^T}$.

Comment: Why is that the problem? Because it is to much computation or because you don't know how?

Comment: There are infinitely many $B$ such that $B^TB=A^TA+\lambda I$ for a fixed $A$ and $\lambda$. For which $B$ then you want to solve $Bx=z$?